# C++ socket programming, multicast with compression, any good libraries/wrappers?

Tags: c++, sockets, compression, multicast

I am beginning to get into socket programming. Currently, I am transferring data between server and clients using scp which scales very poorly when dealing with streams of data (it seems like each new scp session needs to open a new TCP connection and this really slows down the speed).

I would like to transfer text to multiple clients, over a day, this text could reach a couple gigabytes in size so implementing some sort of compression is key.

Can anybody recommend some good libraries or wrappers which can simplify writing this code?  The standard C++ sockets interface is quite cumbersome to work with.  So far, my only lead is Boost ASIO but that doesn't seem to have compression capabilities. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: With SSL, you should be able to enable gzip compression on your data.

Comment: How exactly do you plan to multicast streams more efficient than opening a TCP socket for each client? How are you going to handle retries and duplicates?

Comment: Isn't multicast essentially opening a TCP socket to each client and keeping it open as you stream data to each client?  I want a multicast because I want each client to get the same data at the same time.

Comment: TCP cannot be multicast. Think about it - how could a protocol that guarantees delivery handle multicast?

Comment: So what are the best protocols to use for compressed multicast?

Comment: Pragmatic General Multicast (PGM) would probably be best for this, if you really want UDP with multicast. Though frankly, TCP really doesn't perform so badly unless you really have **a lot** of clients (like, thousands). I would guess it's the SSL bit of SCP that slows you down, not the TPC handshake. Compress and encrypt your data once with standard libraries (zlib and crypto++) and just send them via a TCP socket, and you're good. Really. TCP is good at pushing a bulk of data over the network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try [UDT](http://udt.sourceforge.net/).

UDT is a reliable UDP based application level data transport protocol for distributed data intensive applications over wide area high-speed networks. UDT uses UDP to transfer bulk data with its own reliability control and congestion control mechanisms.

I dont really know if the compression is available ...

Comment: The documentation doesn't seem to mention compression.  But it looks like a good solution for transport.  You can always compress before sending and decompress after receiving.

Comment: "reliable UDP" = reinventing TCP, with all the 30 years of trial and error to get the parameters 'just right' for throughput/latency/bandwith...

Answer (score 2):

For the compression part, you can use [zlib](http://zlib.net/).  There are many [C++ interfaces](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/iostreams/doc/home.html) out there for zlib, or you can use it directly to compress and decompress messages.

Answer (score 1):

Compression and multicast are two orthogonal issues. As said by previous posters, pick a compression library best suited for your data.

For multicast there are multiple options, OpenPGM and RSP are open source.